# iTextSharp adding rectangular annotation instead of quad

Tags: c#, .net, itext, itextpdf, pdf-annotations

I am using the following code to add Annotations to an existing PDF using iTextSharp and C#. The problem is that the shape of annotation highlight is quad, but what I need is a rectangular annotation. Also, is there a way to suppress the sticky note getting added to each annotation?

```
float[] quad =
{
  rect.Rect.Left,
  rect.Rect.Bottom,
  rect.Rect.Right,
  rect.Rect.Bottom,
  rect.Rect.Left,
  rect.Rect.Top,
  rect.Rect.Right,
  rect.Rect.Top
};

PdfAnnotation highlight = PdfAnnotation.CreateMarkup(stamper.Writer, rect.Rect, 
Constants.vbNull.ToString(), PdfAnnotation.MARKUP_HIGHLIGHT, quad);
```

[image: Click here to view Image representing the annotation shape & sticky note problem]

Comment: Have you tried giving the quadrilateral coordinates counterclockwise?

Comment: Hi @mkl, I tried the quad in reverse order but it messes up the location of annotation. 
                                float[] quad = {
                                    rect.Rect.Right,
                                    rect.Rect.Bottom,
                                    rect.Rect.Left,
                                    rect.Rect.Bottom,
                                    rect.Rect.Right,
                                    rect.Rect.Top,
                                    rect.Rect.Left,
                                    rect.Rect.Top
                                };

Comment: Neither the original nor the other order is counterclockwise. But the counterclockwise 
order is required by the specification.

Comment: Hi mkl, can you post a sample of order please.

Comment: Ok, I looked deeper into this, and it looks like **(A)** Adobe Reader does not work according to specification here, cf. e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9855814/1729265), but expects the quadpoints in the order TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight, and **(B)** Adobe Reader by default draws its markup quads with *rounded* left and right sides... But the specification requires "*The annotation dictionary’s **AP** entry, if present, shall take precedence over **QuadPoints***"; thus, to really get rectangular markups you might succeed by creating your own appearance streams.